# Why ECommerce addImpression event returns an error?

Tags: google-analytics, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm using `Prestashop 1.6.1.3` and trying to add `google analytics ecommerce` but i have problem.

I'm checking that problem on Analytics debugger extensions

Here is my request :

```
ga("ec:addImpression", {id: "1148", name: ""iPhone 5\/5S K\u00fc\u00e7\u00fck K\u0131z Desenli Pembe Silikon K\u0131l\u0131f"", category: ""iphone-5-5s-kiliflari"", brand: "", variant: "null", position: 10, list: "category", price: "9.99"})
```

Here is the error response :

```
Tracker does not have any plugins
```

[image: Error pic]

That is, first load from debugging is showing no error to send data and real time report is working perfectly.
[image]

Comment: The problem might be that your tracker does not have any plugins :-) Can you check if your GA code contains something like ga('require', 'ec'); (the line that includes the EEC plugin) ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff Thank you so much. When i add ga('require', 'ec');  every think is perfect :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error `Tracker does not have any plugins` means that you didn't include the`Enhanced Ecommerce` plugin.

You should add this code to your page

```
ga('require', 'ec');
```

[More information on google official guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#loadit)

Comment: But this is not mandatory as per docs to add `Enhanced ECommerec` right?